# Spring Boot CRUD edit profile / updating profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, crud

I am having a bit of trouble trying to understand how to edit a profile via Spring Boot Hibernate. Note that this project does not include thymeleaf or spring security.

I am trying to grab the logged in user and grab his email instance to be able to update it in a JSP called editProfile.jsp. The My Profile link on my welcome page should grab the logged in user's information and take you to the editProfile jsp where a user can edit the information and update the information.
As of right now I have tried a few things and none of them seem to work.

**I keep getting this stack trace**

```
    There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountForm' available as request attribute
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountForm' available as request attribute
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:460)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.editProfile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(editProfile_jsp.java:353)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.editProfile_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(editProfile_jsp.java:285)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.editProfile_jsp._jspService(editProfile_jsp.java:236)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I thought I had everything set up but apparently I don't so I decided to post my problem here.

**This is a picture of my Welcome page so you have a general idea of what I am talking about, the "My Profile link at the top right should take me to editProfile.jsp. As you can also see, I was able to successfully add the logged in user's name and output it onto the welcome page from the login controller**

[image: Welcome Page]

**This is the welcome.jsp**

```
    <header id = bal>
        <input type="image" src="images/nav_logo.PNG" name="nav" class="btSubmit" id="nav" />
        <nav>
            <ul id = nav__links>
                <li><a style = 'text-decoration: none' href = > Testing Center </a> </li>
                <li><a style = 'text-decoration: none' href = > Donation Center </a></li>
                <li> <a style = 'text-decoration: none' href = 'https://www.youtube.com/' > Shop </a></li>
                <li><a style = 'text-decoration: none' href = "/welcome/edit/${firstName.email}"> My Profile </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    
    </header>
    <body>
    <p> Welcome, ${firstName.firstName} ${firstName.lastName}</p>
    
    <div class = grid>
        <div id = card1>
            <h1 class = headstuff>Welcome!</h1>
            <p id=" divider1">Practice social distancing by putting space
                between yourself and others. Continue to practice healthy habits,
                like washing your hands for at least twenty seconds and staying home if you are sick,
                to help slow the spread of <a href = https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/index.html style="color:#817ffe;">#COVID19</a>.</p>
            <button id = butt1>Resources</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id = butt2>Self-check</button>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class = grid id = g2>
        <div class = card2>
            <img class = icon src="images/world.png" >
            <h2 style = 'display: inline-block' class=" sechead"> Global News</h2>
            <p class = pnew>
                Since the beginning of the pandemic, accelerating the development of and equitable access to vaccines,
                diagnostics and therapeutics for COVID-19 has been a priority for WHO.
                Already, we have made remarkable progress.
                </p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="/news">
                <input type="submit" class=butt3 value="View"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    
        <div class = card3>
            <img class = icon src="images/flag.png" >
            <h2 style = 'display: inline-block' class=" sechead"> US News</h2>
            <p class = pnew>Since the beginning of the pandemic, accelerating the development of and equitable access to vaccines,
                diagnostics and therapeutics for COVID-19 has been a priority for WHO.
                Already, we have made remarkable progress.
            </p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="/news">
                <input type="submit" class=butt3 value="View"/>
            </form>
    
        </div>
    
        <div class = card4>
            <img class = icon src="images/cap.png" id = icon>
            <h2 style = 'display: inline-block' class=" sechead" id = cardt> Georgia News</h2>
            <p class = pnew id = pn>Since the beginning of the pandemic, accelerating the development of and equitable access to vaccines,
                diagnostics and therapeutics for COVID-19 has been a priority for WHO.
                Already, we have made remarkable progress.
            </p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="/news">
                <input type="submit" class=butt3 value="View"/>
            </form>
    </div>
    
        <div class = card5>
            <img class = icon src="images/bulld.png" id = ic4>
            <h2 style = 'display: inline-block' class=" sechead" > Athens News</h2>
            <p class = pnew>Since the beginning of the pandemic, accelerating the development of and equitable access to vaccines,
                diagnostics and therapeutics for COVID-19 has been a priority for WHO.
                Already, we have made remarkable progress.
            </p>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="/news">
                <input type="submit" class=butt3 value="View"/>
            </form>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Here is my login controller to see how I was able to pass the data from login controller to welcome.jsp**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Object submitLoginIn(@ModelAttribute("login") AccountEntity accountForm, Model model) {
    
            AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(accountForm.getEmail().toLowerCase());
    
            // Password Verifier using Argon2
            Argon2PasswordEncoder argon2PasswordEncoder = new Argon2PasswordEncoder();
            boolean passwordMatch = argon2PasswordEncoder.matches(accountForm.getPassword(), accountInstance.getPassword());
    
            // issue where if i use caps email, throws null pointer exception
            if (accountInstance == null || !passwordMatch) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Email or Password");
                // return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
                return "login";
            } else if (accountInstance.isEnabled() == false) {
                System.out.println("Cant login cause not verified");
                return "login";
            } else {
                System.out.println("account exist");
                model.addAttribute("firstName", accountInstance);
                return "welcome";
            }
    
        }
    }
```

**Here is my Welcome Controller, This is probably the issue but I am totally drawing a blank**

```
    @Controller
    public class WelcomeController {
    
        AccountRepository accountRepo;
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showWelcmPage(Model model) {
            return "welcome";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "welcome/edit/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getEditUserData(@PathVariable("email") String email, Model model, AccountEntity accountForm) {
    
            model.addAttribute("accountEmail", email);
            return "editProfile";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "editProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showEditProfilePage(Model model, AccountEntity accountForm) {
            model.addAttribute("email", accountForm.getEmail());
            model.addAttribute("password", accountForm.getPassword());
            return "editProfile";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "editProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String sendEditProfilePage(@ModelAttribute("accountForm") AccountEntity accountForm, Model model) {
            AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(accountForm.getEmail());
    
            accountInstance.setEmail(accountForm.getEmail());
            accountInstance.setPassword(accountForm.getPassword());
    
            accountRepo.save(accountForm);
    
            return "editProfile";
        }
    
        // @RequestMapping(value = "editProfile/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        // public String Data(@PathVariable("email") String email, Model model) {
        // AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(email);
    
        // model.addAttribute("accountForm", accountInstance);
        // return "editProfile";
        // }
    }
```

**Last but not least my AccountEntity**

```
    @Entity(name = "user")
    public class AccountEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String userName;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        // private String gender;
        private Integer age;
        private Date createdDate;
        private boolean enabled;
    
        @Column(updatable = false)
        private String verificationCode;
    
        // Getters and Setters
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
    
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    
        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
    
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
    
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
        /*
         * public String getGender() { return gender; }
         * 
         * public void setGender(String gender) { this.gender = gender; }
         */
    
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    
        public String getVerificationCode() {
            return verificationCode;
        }
    
        public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
            this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
        }
    
        public Date getCreatedDate() {
            return createdDate;
        }
    
        public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }
    
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }
    
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the @Autowired annotation above my AccountRepository declaration in my Welcome Controller

Comment: When are you getting this error? I assume it is when you try to submit the form in editProfile.jsp. If I&#39;m right, show the jsp. If not, explain when the exception is thrown.